# Local Maxima block simulink

Tags: matlab, block, simulink

I have a `128 x 1` input in block `'Local maxima'`. I want to take as an output, the `4` maximum values of an input. I set: Maximum number of local maxima: `4`, and Neighborhood size: `[1 1]`. I expect to take an `2x4` matrix each has in the first row the values I want. However, this block outputs `2` matrices with size `2x4`. Why does it happend?

**EDIT:** I use the `'simout'` to spectate the output of block `'Local maxima'`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a Display block? Could it be that it outputs a 2x4 matrix at each time step and in `simout` you get all of the time steps?

Comment: Every time i execute my simulation this block results the 2x2x4 matrix. I display the values using simout. Take a look: 

http://prntscr.com/4yqqy2

Comment: .... and http://prntscr.com/4yqt58

Comment: Can you display the signal dimensions (Display -> Signals & Ports -> Signal Dimensions) and check that the input really is 128x1, and the output really 2x4? You haven't tried what I suggested: instead of using simout, use a Display block. I suspect it is outputtting a 2x4 matrix, but at each time step, so 5the third (or maybe even first) dimension in your `simout` variable is time. Don't use `simout` for now.

Comment: You are completely right! http://prntscr.com/4yqzus

However, if i try to connect this output with a "Submatrix" block i take this error: http://prntscr.com/4yr0so

Thats why i supposed that it was a dimension error.

Comment: You can't do that. The Local Maxima block outputs a variable-size signal, whereas the submatrix only accepts fixed-size inputs. You need to untick the "Output variable-size signal" in the Local Maxima block.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the output of the block is probably a 2x4 matrix, but at each time step. If you have, say 101 time steps (from 0 to 10s in steps of 0.1), then the input signal is not 128x1, but 128x1x101, and so the output that is stored in `simout` will be 2x4x101.

Comment: I have not found a block which can give me only the 2D matrix ( the 2x4 matrix i want). Do you have something in your mind? Thanks again!

Comment: You don't understand: Simulink is for time-based simulations, that's the very essence of Simulink. Any block will output you a signal: a signal is something that varies with time. A parameter is a constant that does not vary. The block does exactly what you want **at each time step**. What you want is a parameter, that's not what Simulink blocks do. If you want to do static calculations, independent of time, use MATLAB, not Simulink.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he is trying to do is:

To produce a 2-dimensional matrix/array directly from Simulink. In other words, when data is exported.. the 3rd dimensional for time should be omitted. Can this happen?

I understand that taking the output and editing it with matlab so that it becomes from 3-dimensional a 2-dimensional array is trivial. But is the above possible?

Comment: Well you can always post-process the data in MATLAB and extract the matrix at a particular time step, e.g. `M = simout.signals.values(:,:,2);` but as I said, he/she shouldn't probably use Simulink in the first place, it kind of defeats the purpose of Simulink.